# Azure Function Best Practices

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

## Detail

I am new to azure function. I am trying to create azure Function to send (email,sms and notifications). I firstly create 3 different functions Http triggered for this. My question is there is a good way to create a generic function for all of the above mentioned function as one function and is it a good way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to provide an answer for this because it will usually depend on the details of your application but I can provide this general guidance:

1. You'll end up with a more reliable system if you make each function do the smallest amount of work possible. So to take your example, having separate functions for sending email, sms and push notifications is a good approach as a failure in any one of those paths will not prevent the others from working.
2. Where possible, connect multiple functions together with queues. Try to only use HTTP when you have a client that requires a response of some sort.

I'm going to make some assumptions about your scenario so that I can illustrate an example. Lets say you need to expose a HTTP triggered function to send a notification. A design that maximizes reliability might look something like this:

1. A HTTP triggered function recieves a payload with a target user and message and writes this to a `notify` queue then returns OK to client
2. A queue triggered function reading from the `notify` queue then looks up notification addresses from db/cache, writes messages to `sms` queue, `email` queue, `push` queue as appropriate.
3. Separate queue triggered functions for `sms`, `email` and `push` each read from their queue and then make the call to the appropriate service, using the address details written into the message.

Comment: One question from your answer if we send the message in queue let's say email queue. User send it to queue and we get that message and then send it to the user and we got an error let's say invalid email then how we send back the exception message to the user back all the way?

Comment: I think the most common way to achieve this is with the "long running operation with polling" pattern (http://restalk-patterns.org/long-running-operation-polling.html). Basically you model the operation as a long running job that you can request status for. It is true that this is typically more complex to implement than to make your operation synchronously handle errors and return them to the client directly. It is a tradeoff between reliability vs ease of implementation.

Comment: I'll add that functions does have a preview feature called "durable functions" that can help make things easier if you decide to implement things as long running jobs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview#pattern-3-async-http-apis